# Group as a category of 2 objects vs as a category of one object

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, category-theory

What are the advantages of viewing a group as a category of one object as opposed to this category of two objects:

First object : The set of group elements

Second objects : The set of ordered pairs of group elements

Morphism : Group product, taking each ordered pair to their product

This Category sounds like the natural interpretation of a binary operation : $*: G\times G\rightarrow G$

But why is group seen as a category of one object instead?

Comment: A monoid is obviously a category with one object and you're just concerned with the morphisms.  A group is then a monoid where each morphism has an inverse.  You don't need the binary operation as composition of morphisms is automatic in a category.

Comment: An object isn't a set, unless you are in the category $\mathsf{Set}$.

Comment: You seem to be describing a **group object** in $\mathsf{Set}$, which is equivalent to a group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't a category because there are no identity morphisms. One thing you could do is let the objects be elements of the group and morphisms be multiplication by elements of the group. For instance, $h \mapsto gh$ under the morphism $g_h$.

The standard picture of a group as a category with one element and invertible morphisms is simply identifying all of the objects as one because the morphisms alone carry all the information about the group based on how they compose. The advantage of this approach is that a monoid with invertible morphisms is precisely equivalent to a group.